# How do I increase the width of a curved line drawn using a bezier pen?

Tags: inkscape, path

I have used the bezier curve tool in Inkscape and I get the following line:

[image]

For the above drawing I had used the bezier curve and selected the "Create Spiro Path" option and under "Shape" selected the "None" option. Now when I go to "Path -> Path Effects", I see no option of increasing the thinkness of this line. How do I increase the thickness of this line?

P.S. When I select the shape "Ellipse" and draw a curve, I do see an option of "width" like so:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Inkscape 0.92.1 yes.

So, you've added a Spiro Path, which is in fact a path effect, with the "Triangle in" shape set - which also now includes a Power Stroke effect in the newest Inkscape.

1. Select your path with the Edit Path's by Node Tool. The very first node turns pink. This is actually the Power Stroke control.
2. If you click and drag that pink node it will thicken the line.

Example of Spiro stroke selected, showing path effects applied.

[image: Spiro stroke selected]

Example of clicking and dragging the Power Stroke control.

[image: Clicking and dragging the Power Stroke control]

You don't even need to use the "triangle in" setting, if you have an ordinary stroked path, or a spiro path, you can add the Power Stroke effect.  If you do that you get even more control with 3 Power Stroke controls which you can use to alter the thickness of the line. The top stroke below is a Spiro, the lower is an ordinary stroked path.

[image: Example applying Power Stroke to ordinary stroked paths]

There's also similar functionality to the Pattern Along a Path effect, this time a circular control point controls thickness of the pattern.

[image: Example showing control of thickness of Pattern Along a Path effect]

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I had missed totally this functinality and indirectly claimed the questioner to be an idiot. +1. Deleted that post.

Comment: I only discovered this recently, it's a new feature.